# "HtmlUnit" Driver with Jmeter shows errors in javascript

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to add a "WebDriver Sampler" in Jmeter with  "HtmlUnit Driver Config". Have written a simple come, which opens a webpage. But in the back ground, there are tons of errors / warnings related to JS and CSS, present in the web page.
Something like this

```
2018-06-19 11:57:45,993 WARN c.g.h.IncorrectnessListenerImpl: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
```

Some of the previous questions  says its due to old JARs, but I have all latest.
1. Is there any way to solve this ?
2. Can we set logLevel in the webdriver sampler ?

Answer (score 0):

1. No one will be able to provide answer to point 1 unless you provide the URL of the page  you're trying to test.

   Looking into the warning itself - it indicates a bug in your system under test as valid Content-Type for JavaScript should be [`application/javascript`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329#page-10) so you can raise a defect to get this fixed.
2. If you totally sure that the behavior is expected and there are no plans to fix these "tons of errors" you can add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation under `<Loggers>` tag:

   ```
   <Logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit" level="fatal"/>
   ```

   See [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) article for more information on tuning JMeter logging subsystem.